# Из двух моделей сделать одно View Asp MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Не могу решить одну проблему , потому-что плохо разбираюсь во `ViewModel`.

Есть у меня две модели. Это тип учетной единицы

```
public class Ue_type
{
    [Display(Name = "ID")]
    [Key]
    public int Id { set; get; }

    [Display(Name = "Тип")]
    [StringLength(200)]
    [Column(TypeName = "char")]
    public string Type_Name { set; get; }
}
```

А это модель учетной единицы

```
public class Ue_model
{
    [Display(Name = "ID")]
    [Key]
    public int Id { set; get; }

    [Display(Name = "Модель УЕ")]
    [StringLength(200)]
    [Column(TypeName = "char")]
    public string Model_Name { set; get; }
    public int UetypeId { set; get; }
}
```

В типе мы пишем к примеру  Монитор, Ноутбук, Принтер и тд... А в модел мы описывает модель Samsung S22  и плюс идентификатор типа 1.

Так вот я хочу все это дело вывести во `View`. В таком виде

```
[__Модель____][__Тип____]
[Samsung S22 ][ Монитор ]  
[Kyocera 102 ][ Принтер ]
```

Я сделал контроллер

```
public ActionResult Ue_Models()
{

    var model_res = (from m in db.Ue_model
                    join t in db.Ue_type
                    on m.UetypeId equals t.Id
                    select new
                    {
                        m.Model_Name,
                        t.Type_Name

                    }).ToList();


    return View(model_res);
}
```

Правильно я объединил две модели с помощью `LINQ`? И как мне теперь все это вывести во `View`. И если возможно приведите пример `ViewModel` очень хочу на данном примере разобраться во `ViewModel`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для того, чтобы вывести во `View` то, что Вы хотите, Вам необходимо описать модель, которая объединяет Ваши две модели.

То есть Вы должны описать модель, а в контроллере подготовить данные и передать их в представление.

---

Создать модель:

```
public class DoubleModel
{
    // код модели...(пример)
    public string ModelName { get; set; }
    public string ModelType { get; set; }  

    public DoubleModel() { }
}
```

---

В представлении, опишем нашу модель, которую будем ждать:

```
@model IEnumerable<DoubleModel>
// код представления...(пример)
@if (Model.Any())
{
    <table> 
        <thead> 
             <tr>
                 <th>Модель</th>
                 <th>Тип</th>
             </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            foreach (var ue in Model)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>@ue.ModelName</td>
                    <td>@ue.ModelType</td>
                </tr>
            }
         </tbody>
    </table>
}
```

---

Контроллер будет давать нам необходимые данные:

```
public ActionResult Ue_Models()
{
    var model = (from m in db.Ue_model
        join t in db.Ue_type
        on m.UetypeId equals t.Id
        select new DoubleModel
        {
           ModelName = m.Model_Name,
           ModelType = t.Type_Name
        }).ToList(); 

    // подготовка данных на основе Вашего кода (пример)
    return View(model);
}
```

---

Приведенный код проиллюстрирован как пример, необходимо подогнать приведенный пример кода под свой код. Сама идея должны быть понятна.